# First website html only takes half page

Tags: html, css

I am having problems with my code only filling up half the screen. It will fill the left half but not the right. I tried setting html height and width to 100% but it did not fix the problem. I also could not click on my href's to other pages after doing this. Any help would be great.

```css
        html {
         margin: 0;
         height: 100%;
         width: 100%;
        }
        body {
         background: #B2906F;
         font-family: arial;
         margin: 0;
         height: 100%;
        }
        
        .picture{
         display: inline;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         position: fixed;
         z-index: -1;
         background-size: 100%
        }
        
        .button{
         padding: 10px 15px;
         text-decoration: none;
         border-radius: 5px;
         background-color: #05280c
        }
        .button-primary:hover {
         background-color: #05370c
        }
        
        h1 {
         display: inline;
         margin: 0;
         background-color: #2c421f;
         padding: 5px;
         position: absolute;
        }
        
        ul{
         margin: 0;
         display: inline;
         padding: 0px 0px 0px 250px;
        }
        ul li {
         display: inline-block;
         list-style-type: none;
         padding: 15px 10px;
         color: #050c0c;
         margin: 0;
        }
        
        ul li a {
         color: black;
        }
        
        footer{
         clear: both;
        }
        
        nav {
         color: 
         height: 40px;
         margin: 0;
         background-color: #2c421f;
        }
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
        <html>
         <head>
          <title>NWWolfPack</title>
          <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
         </head>
         
         <body>
          <h1>NW Wolf Pack</h1>
          <div class="picture"><img src="camo.jpg" width="1000" height="150">
             <header> 
           <nav>
            <ul>
             <li class="button"><strong>Home</strong></li>
             <li><a href="records.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Records</strong></a></li>
             <li><a href="membership.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Membership</strong></a></li>
             <li><a href="contactus.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
           </nav>
          </header>
         </body>
         
         
         <footer>2017 Dillan Hall</footer>
        </html>
```

Comment: hi @dillan can you paste your HTML code pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your code in a main div and add a width width `margin: 0 auto`

```
.mainContainer{
    width:990px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This centered my page but it still does not cover the entire page. Thank you for responding.